# Update tile notication by using alarm schedule in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-process

`It possible for windows phone updated tile by using alarm?`

When the alarm is trigger, the tile will be updated. I tired searching method that update tile notification in certain time in the background. Any guild line or resources can be pointed?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

No.

It is not possible to have the firing of an alarm trigger the updating of a tile. There is no way to have code run (to update a tile or otherwise) in response to an alarm being triggered.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Lacey. May i ask got other method that same function as alarm manager in android?

Comment: @likewer No, Windows Phone has nothing comparable. There is no way to schedule your app/code to run at a certain point in the future. Windows Mobile had the "State and Notification Broker (SNAPI)" which is comparable. Maybe (hopefully) that will reappear at some point in the future. In the mean time the nearest closest option you have would be a periodic task and not do anything in it until a certain time. Beware the time the periodic task is invoked can't be controlled though and there are limitations in what you can do in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an alarm would work,  but have you explored periodic tasks?